# New files getting wrong permissions from setacl

Tags: permissions, samba, acl

I'm trying to create a file from windows on a mapped samba share, but after creating the file, I'm unable to edit it. For some reason the mask is changing to rw- even though my default is set to rwx. umask is 0022, but I think the ACL overrides the umask.

Is something wrong with the permissions of the folder? I want bob and admins to have rwx to files.

```
[root@server02 folder]# getfacl .
# file: .
# owner: nobody
# group: admins
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:bob:rwx
group::---
group:admins:rwx
mask::rwx
other::rwx
default:user::rwx
default:user:bob:rwx
default:group::---
default:group:admins:rwx
default:mask::rwx
default:other::rwx

[root@server02 folder]# getfacl test
# file: test
# owner: bob
# group: admins
user::rwx
user:bob:rwx               #effective:rw-
group::---
group:admins:rwx      #effective:rw-
mask::rw-
other::---
```

Comment: The effective acl is a combination of extended ACL and mask. The mask is also group acl (not the extended acl) permission (can someone explain me why its so?)